# Xcode syntax highlighting and code completion not working only for Swift

Tags: xcode

I am currently working on a project and recently pulled changes from Git, since that pull my Xcode has been affected. In Swift files syntax highlighting and code completion no longer works, the code suggestions I get when typing are based on the content currently in the file. I've tried deleting Derived Data and cache files but that doesn't seem to have worked. In my project I created an Objective-C file to see if it worked for that and it did, it had the sort of suggestions I wanted. I then created a Swift playground and it worked for that too. It seems that my issue is only affecting .swift files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with compile sources under the build phases in the project file. All files were removed so I had to add each file into it and the code completion is back.